# Qgis C++ plugin translation

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, c++

I'm having issues with the translation of my Qgis plugin.

`static const QString sName = QObject::tr( "Editeur Monoscopique 3D" );`

`MyClass::MyClass( QgisInterface * theQgisInterface ):
    QgisPlugin( sName)
{` 
        `QSettings tSettings; 

        QString qsUserLocale = tSettings.value( "locale/userLocale", "" ).toString();`

```
    if ( ( qsUserLocale != "fr_FR" ) && ( qsUserLocale != "fr" ) )
    {
            QString qsTranslationPath = ":/prefix/en_US.qm" ;
            QFileInfo tFileInfo (qsTranslationPath) ;
            if (tFileInfo.exists())
            {
                    //QTranslator translator;
                    if (m_tTranslator.load( "en_US", ":/prefix" ) )
                            qApp->installTranslator(&m_tTranslator);
            }
    }
```

}

The problem is that `sName` is declared before installing the translator 
`qApp->installTranslator(&m_tTranslator);` and so its text is not translated !

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement name() anyway, so I would consider sName as the internal name and set up another member value to hold the user-visible name. Set its final value after installing the translator and most cases should be covered.

Comment: The problem is that Qgis plugin manager takes what is held in "sName" to be displayed so even if I set up another member value to hold the name it won't be taken to display by the plugin manager !

Comment: I suggest you file a bug/feature request on http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis then. C++ plugins bundled with QGIS don't have this problem, since they use the main QGIS translation domain. You could maybe also hack around the issue by abusing the non-const return-by-reference name() variant, but I wouldn't advise it.